# Counting all possible way of onto function

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a question like counting the onto function. Given a set $X = \{1,2,...n\}$ and set $Y = \{1,2,3,...\}$. Now we denote $S_n$ be the number of counting those onto function such that $f :X \rightarrow Y$ if there's $i \geq 1$ and $f$ is onto the subset $\{1,2,3,...,i\} \subset Y$. For instance, let $S_0 = 1$, and $S_1 = 1$ since 1 maps to 1. Moreover, $S_2 = 3$ since we have two subset, one is when $i = 1,$then $i = \{1\}$ and $i = 2$,then $i = \{1,2\}$.  Now from the domain $X=\{1,2\}$. So either $\{1,2\}$ from X maps to $\{1\}$ or $1 \rightarrow 1, 2 \rightarrow 2$ and $1 \rightarrow 2, 2 \rightarrow 1.$

The question first asks to find $S_3$, and I found $S_3 = 9$, it's easy if we list and count all the combination of onto function for $i=1,2,3$ respectively. But then the question asks to find the recurrence relation of $S_n$, I'm essentially stuck here for a while. Any suggestion to help me go further?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the problem, but isn't $S_3=13$? There is one function onto $\{1\}$, there are $6$ functions onto $\{1,2\}$ (`112`, `121`, `211`, `221`, `212`, `122`), and $6$ functions onto $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: There are actually $2^n-2$ functions from $X=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ onto $\{0,1\}$: each of those functions is completely determined by $\{k\in X:f(k)=1\}$, and that set can be any of the $2^n$ subsets of $X$ except $\varnothing$ and $X$ itself. What, if any, is the relationship between $n$ and $i$? It really isn’t clear just which functions $S_n$ is supposed to be counting.

Comment: I believe it is http://oeis.org/A000670, which I found by counting $S_4=75$ and searching for $1,3,13,75$.  The claimed recurrence is $2a_n=(a+1)^n$ where the superscripts are converted to subscripts after expansion and $a_0=1$

Comment: @RossMillikan: And that recurrence boils down to $a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}ka_k$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  I realized that as I tried to validate it for $n=4$, which worked.  I don't immediately see how to derive it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me, $S_3$ is indeed 13 and it's the mistake on my part. However, what's the intuition behind this recurrence, i.e. how's it relate to my question?

Comment: @RossMillikan: To rank $n$ people, allowing ties, pick out a non-empty subset of $n-k$ of them to finish equal first and then rank the remaining $k$ in $a_k$ ways behind the co-winners.

Answer (score 2):

$S_n$ is the number of functions $f$ from $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to itself such that $\operatorname{ran}f=[k]$ for some $k\in[n]$: that is, $S_n$ is the number of functions that map $[n]$ onto an initial segment of itself. Suppose that we know $S_k$ for $k<n$ and want to calculate $S_n$.

If $f$ maps $[n]$ **onto** an initial segment of itself, $f$ must map a non-empty subset of $[n]$ to $1$. Say that $f$ maps $\ell$ elements of $[n]$ to $1$; there are $\binom{n}\ell$ ways to choose those $\ell$ elements of $[n]$. The remaining $n-\ell$ members of $[n]$ must be mapped onto an initial segment of $\{2,3,\ldots,n\}$. There are exactly as many ways to do this as there are to map $[n-\ell]$ onto an initial segment of $[n-1]$, and there are $S_{n-\ell}$ of those. Thus, there are $\binom{n}\ell S_{n-\ell}$ maps from $[n]$ to itself that map exactly $\ell$ members of $[n]$ to $1$.

The possible values of $\ell$ are $1,2,\ldots,n$, so

$$S_n=\sum_{\ell=1}^n\binom{n}\ell S_{n-\ell}\;.$$

We can make this recurrence look a bit nicer by letting $k=n-\ell$ and using the fact that $\binom{n}\ell=\binom{n}{n-\ell}=\binom{n}k$ to rewrite it as

$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}kS_k\;.$$